# Questions regarding the proof of quantifier elimination of DLO

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

So this is the proof in David Marker's Model theory book, Theorem 3.1.3.

I am a bit confused over the first line of the proof. It reads :

"First suppose $\phi$ is a sentence. If $\mathbb{Q}\models\phi$, then because DLO is complete, DLO $\models \phi$ and

DLO $\models \phi \leftrightarrow x_1 = x_1$"

My questions is

1.) Where does completeness come into play here ? $\mathbb{Q}$ by itself is a model of DLO, so $\phi$ is already a logical consequence of DLO, why do I need completeness ?

2.) Why is $\phi$ equivalent to a tautology here ?

Thanks in advance. Cheers !

Comment: Why would $\phi$ be a logical consequence of DLO?

Comment: @EricWofsey My understanding is that, we say $T \models \phi$ if $M\models \phi$ whenever $M$ is a model of $T$. So in this case $\mathbb{Q}$ is a model of DLO, and by assumption $\mathbb{Q}\models \phi$. But in the case where my understanding is wrong, my question still remains: where does completeness come into play here ? Thanks for the help

Comment: You seem to have your quantifiers mixed up: $T\models\phi$ means that $M\models\phi$ for _every_ model $M$ of $T$, not for _some_ model $M$ of $T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: your first question, the issue is that *different models of a theory might behave differently*. Remember that "$\Gamma\models\chi$" means "**every** model of $\Gamma$ satisfies $\chi$" - this is an easy point to get tripped up on. Basically, the issue is that a specific case doesn't tell you too much about the general case.

Knowing that $\mathbb{Q}\models$ DLO and $\mathbb{Q}\models \phi$ just tells you that $\phi$ is *consistent* with DLO; other models of DLO might satisfy $\neg\phi$. For example, letting $G$ be your favorite abelian group and Grp be the group axioms, we have that $G\models$ Grp and $G\models x_1*x_2=x_2*x_1$, but we know that $x_1*x_2=x_2*x_1$ **isn't** a logical consequence of Grp (since there are non-abelian groups).

However, DLO is *complete*, so any sentence true in *some* model of DLO is true in *every* model of DLO. Put another way, anything true in some model of DLO - like $\mathbb{Q}$ - is a logical consequence of DLO; there's no "possible-but-not-necessary" going on here.

---

Now for your second question, look back at the definition of "equivalent" - two sentences $\psi,\theta$ are equivalent *over a theory $T$* if $T$ entails $\psi\leftrightarrow\theta$.

One easy way this could happen is if $T$ entails each sentence separately; that is, if $T$ entails $\psi$ and $T$ entails $\theta$. This is because (think back to truth tables) $\psi\leftrightarrow\theta$ is true in a structure iff either both $\psi$ and $\theta$ are true in that structure or both $\psi$ and $\theta$ are false in that structure; if $T\models\psi$ and $T\models\theta$ then both $\psi$ and $\theta$ are true in every model of $T$, so $\psi\leftrightarrow\theta$ is true in every model of $T$. (And of course we'd get the same behavior of $T$ entails the *negation* of each sentence separately.) That's what's going on in this case:

- $\mathbb{Q}$ is a model of DLO and satisfies $\phi$.
- Since DLO is complete, this means *every* model of DLO satisfies $\phi$; that is, DLO$\models \phi$.
- And of course DLO $\models x_1=x_1$, since in fact $\emptyset\models x_1=x_1$ (that is, "$x_1=x_1$" is true with respect to every variable assignment in every structure).
- So DLO $\models\phi\leftrightarrow x_1=x_1$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason I asked the 2nd question is that I am "uncomfortable" with the converse, meaning $x_1 = x_1 \rightarrow \phi$. So looking back once more, this means every model of $x_1 = x_1$ is a model of $\phi$. But is this true ?

Comment: @some1fromhell Every model **of DLO** in which $x_1=x_1$ is true, is a model of $\phi$. You can't forget the "of DLO" part: when we say that one sentence is equivalent to another, we have to specify what background theory (here, DLO) we're using. *(A minor comment: it would be a bit cleaner to use "$\forall x_1(x_1=x_1)$" instead of "$x_1=x_1$," since to talk about formulas with free variables we need to bring variable assignments into the picture, but let's ignore that for now.)*

Comment: That is: $x_1=x_1$ and $\phi$ probably aren't "logically equivalent" (= equivalent over the empty theory); but we're talking about equivalence *over DLO specifically*. Note that the *stronger* a theory $T$ is, the *coarser* is the corresponding equivalence relation on formulas: if $T_0\subseteq T_1$ then every pair of formulas which are $T_0$-equivalent are also $T_1$-equivalent but not necessarily conversely. (This is related to the **Lindenbaum algebra**.)

Comment: Finally, note that the statement "Every model of DLO in which $x_1=x_1$ is true, is a model of $\phi$" is redundant. Every model of DLO is a model of $\phi$, full stop - we already know DLO $\models\phi$. So a fortiori the statement "every model of DLO in which $\alpha$ is true, is a model of $\phi$" is true - *regardless of what $\alpha$ is*. Removing models from the picture and just focusing on the shape of the reasoning here may help: e.g. if every even number can be written as the sum of two primes, then certainly every even number greater than $17$ can be written as the sum of two primes.